# Issues installing catboost , Xgboost and lgbm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have tried using pip and conda [the codes error are shown in the pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hip5O.jpg) install catboost, on my terminal it's keeps crashing as goes to the other boosters[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCZ3j.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Copy and paste your code into your question and format it as code. You are more likely to get an answer if you describe the steps you have taken to try to solve the problem including the research you've done. See how to ask a good question on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are the errors telling you? That they are not available on the default conda channels you have set up. If you google "how to install xgboost conda" you should see the page https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xgboost at the top of the list. That page shows   conda install -c conda-forge xgboost    should do the trick. This means you are installing the xgboost package from the conda-forge channel. It's a different place for conda packages than the main conda channel. That should work.